# Count occurrence of the certain word and update footer of the input file with that count

Tags: awk, sed

I need to update trailer record of the .txt file with number of certain records found in the file. I am looking for records in the file containing value 'MAM 002', count them and use this count to update trailer record that looks that:

'TLR241        '

So let say I found 20 occurrences of 'MAM 002' in the input file, I want to update trailer record as such:

'TLR20          '

Also I need to keep specific length of the trailer record, in this case trailer record length is 4501 bytes.

Comment: Please add small code examples for the input and the desired output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input/output that shows the strings you mention **in context** inside the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what you should use:

```
awk '/MAM 002/{cnt++} {sub(/TLR[0-9]+/,"TLR"(cnt+0))} 1' file
```

but it's untested of course (and it may not do what you want and there may be a better way to do what you want) since you didn't provide any sample input/output we could test against.

Comment: Thanks again, this worked exactly as I need it.

Comment: Hi Ed, one issue I have is when count goes from 3 digits to 2 digits or 2 to 1 etc, records length get changed. Is there any way to keep the same record length irregardless of the count number? Thank you.

Comment: I expect so. Ask a new question with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates the issue you describe so we can best help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this may work:

Sample file:

```
MAM 002
MAM 002
MAM 002
TLR241
```

The command:

```
sed -i "s/TLR.*/TLR$(grep -c "MAM 002" < file)/" file
```

Output:

```
MAM 002
MAM 002
MAM 002
TLR3
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Command is working only one issue, command changing trailer record length. in my case record length is 4501. How to keep the same record length?

Comment: That means there are other fields in the trailer record. We can recognise the required total because it matches TLR[0-9]+ which is already there, then? Exactly what happens when it goes from TLR99 to TLR100? What character do we discard out of your 4501 to accommodate the extra digit?

Comment: There is no other fields in trailer record, just spaces after. Total record length is 4501 and it should stay that way when it goes from TLR99 to TLR100 etc.